# EV3 Motors not moving even though EV3 has batteries

Tags: ev3, motor

I am new to using the EV3. I have only had it for 3 weeks.

My question is why are my EV3 motors not moving?

I know the motors are new and they are in such a good condition they could be sent back to the factory and resold, but the motors just won't move.

Comment: Last time I checked my EV3 motors didn't have wheels or legs, so they are also obviously not moving. Now if you are trying to make the motors spin and you have problems doing so, you'd need to provide us more details as to how the program you have written to make the motors spin looks like and how you have connected your motors to your EV3 so we can help you find out if you have a mistake in your code or wiring, or whether your motors are truly defective.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do to check on the basic level is to plug the motors into the EV3 brick and try to manually get them to rotate with the on board controls. If you can get them working that way then you know for sure it is not the motors or EV3 control as the problem and likely issues with your program.
If they don't move manually try to switch up the ports and the cables to to see if any combination works or does not.
Also the more obvious piece of advice is to make sure your are plugging motors into the motor ports and not the sensor ports.

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen today in my classroom.

The student did not download the program to the brick. After you write the program, you must download the program to your brick.